# How can I break out of a Kotlin `repeat` loop?

Tags: kotlin

How do I break out of a Kotlin `repeat` loop?
(I see plenty of answers about `forEach`, but I want to see a `repeat`-specific answer.)

- You can't use a naked `return`, because that will return from what contains the `repeat`.
- You can't use `break`, because:

  - if the `repeat` is inside a loop, you'll break *that* loop
  - if the `repeat` is not in a loop, you'll get `'break' and 'continue' are only allowed inside a loop`

These don't work (they are functionally identical):

```
    repeat(5) { idx ->
        println(">> $idx")
        if(idx >= 2)
            return@repeat   // use implicit label
    }

    repeat(5) @foo{ idx ->
        println(">> $idx")
        if(idx >= 2)
            return@foo      // use explicit label
    }
```

In both those cases, you get:

```
>> 0
>> 1
>> 2
>> 3
>> 4
```

(The `return@` in both those blocks actually acts like a `continue`, which you can see yourself if you add a `println` after the if-block.)

So how can I break out of a `repeat`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that `repeat` (as well as `forEach`) are not actually loops.  They're *higher-order functions*, that is, they are functions that take functions as parameters.

*(I find this frustrating: They look and act like loops, and feature prominently in the Kotlin docs.  Why not just go all the way and promote them to proper loops in the language?)*

To break out of a `repeat` loop, this is the best answer I can devise:

```
    run repeatBlock@ { // need to make a label outside of the repeat!
        repeat(20) { idx ->
            println(">> $idx")
            if(idx >= 2)
                return@repeatBlock
        }
    }
```

This is the result of that:

```
>> 0
>> 1
>> 2
```

I wish I could do it without introducing a new indent-level, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Having functions that can look like new language syntax isn't just about `repeat()` and `forEach()` — the main advantage is that _you can write your own_!

Comment: They can't be promoted to replace loops, because then... it would be impossible to implement them... :-) Loop is a language construct. `forEach()` is just a function in stdlib and it has to somehow *loop* over items.  You can write your own `forEach2()` function if you need. But you can't redefine loops.

Comment: @broot Guess I need to be explicit: I'm saying that `forEach` and `repeat` _should_ be constructs in a future version.

Comment: They supposedly plan to make `break` and `continue` work with higher order functions eventually, which would be better than breaking compatibility by making them no longer functions.

Comment: That's awesome, @Tenfour04.  Glad to hear it.

Comment: Could also have done `return@run` but yes, it needs to be a label before repeat. Otherwise, it's just returning to the start of repeat - which makes sense: If you were calling a 3rd party function in a standard for-loop and that function had a `break` or `return` in it, you wouldn't want that function to terminate _your_ for-loop, only break/return from _its_ block. Consider the flipside - if you were using a 3rd party library DSL with multiple builder steps, and the first lambda you pass to an inlined fun was `{ return }` it would break the program, rather than cause a compile time error.

Answer (score 7):

That seems like quite an abuse of the `repeat` function. My understanding is that if you write `repeat`, you intend it to repeat for that number of times. Any fewer is surprising.

For your example, I would use a `for` loop:

```
for (idx in 0 until 20) {
    println(">> $idx")
    if (idx >= 2)
        break
}
```

I think using the right tool is better than trying to coerce the wrong one (`repeat`) to do what you want.

---

`repeat` itself is [implemented](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/3acb468d48a2904f6c7d909a1e57c45b794e869a/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt#L151-L157) as a `for` loop:

```
for (index in 0 until times) {
    action(index)
}
```

Trying to use it for anything more than that and you may as well write your own version, rather than wrap up extra behaviour on top of it.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip if i want to retry some action three times and exit if successful, for loop is too verbose. I "repeat trying" 3 times, and exiting is part of try.

Comment: "My understanding is that if you write repeat, you intend it to repeat for that number of times." -- how is that line of thought different when it's a for-loop?  It's not!